# Sharing Google Sheets with a Target Audience using PHP and Google Drive API

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-drive-api, target-audience

I am using PHP and Google Drive API to copy and rename an existing Spreadsheet in Google Drive. I have done this successfully and have learned to give users permissions to my copied files. I would like to share my new copied Spreadsheet with a previously created Target Audience. Is this possible and how would one achieve this.

I tried copying a Spreadsheet that already has a Target Audience and read/write permissions for various users, but the permissions did not carry across from the original to the duplicated file. I have tried to find information about this in the documentation but couldn't find anything relating to it.

Comment: What code and/or tools are you using and what problems or errors do you have?

Comment: did you have any luck finding the audiences API ?